# How to build a Pie chart using Research Kit

Tags: ios, swift3, researchkit

Hi i am new to swift and i tried to build a piechart using research kit app.

i write some code with reference of this [link](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/master/docs/Charts/ChartsAndGraph-template.markdown)

When run my code it showing error 'Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ORK PieChartView DataSource''

please suggest how to solve this issue.

here is my code:

```
import UIKit
    import ResearchKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController,ORKPieChartViewDataSource {


        @IBOutlet weak var pieChartView: ORKPieChartView!
        var colors : NSArray!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

                colors = [
                UIColor(red: 217/225, green: 217/255, blue: 217/225, alpha: 1),
                UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 142/255, blue: 147/255, alpha: 1),
                UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 200/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1)
            ]

            // Connect the pie chart object to a data source
            pieChartView.dataSource = pieChartDataSource

            // Optional custom configuration
            pieChartView.showsTitleAboveChart = false
            pieChartView.showsPercentageLabels = true
            pieChartView.drawsClockwise = true
            pieChartView.titleColor = UIColor.purple
            pieChartView.textColor = UIColor.purple
            pieChartView.title = "Weekly"
            pieChartView.text = "Report"
            pieChartView.lineWidth = 10
            pieChartView.showsPercentageLabels = true

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func numberOfSegmentsInPieChartView(pieChartView: ORKPieChartView ) -> Int {
            return 3
        }

        func pieChartView(_ pieChartView: ORKPieChartView, valueForSegmentAt index: Int) -> CGFloat {
            switch index {
            case 0:
                return 60.0
            case 1:
                return 25.0
            case 2:
                return 15.0
            }

            // Optional methods
            // Give a color to each segment in the pie chart.
            func pieChartView(pieChartView: ORKPieChartView, colorForSegmentAtIndex index: Int) -> UIColor {
                return colors[index]
            }

            // Give a title to each segment in the pie chart.
            func pieChartView(pieChartView: ORKPieChartView, titleForSegmentAtIndex index: Int) -> String {
                switch index {
                case 0:
                    return "Steps taken"
                case 1:
                    return "Tasks completed"
                case 2:
                    return "Surveys completed"
                default:
                    return "task \(index + 1)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The error 'Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'ORK PieChartView DataSource' `means that you are not implemented all
>   the required data source methods`..... Here in your code you wrote a
>   `wrong datasource method` as  `func pieChartView(_ pieChartView:
>   ORKPieChartView, valueForSegmentAt index: Int) -> CGFloat`, change it
>   like below.....

```
func pieChartView(pieChartView: ORKPieChartView, valueForSegmentAt index: Int) -> CGFloat {
                switch index {
                case 0:
                    return 60.0
                case 1:
                    return 25.0
                case 2:
                    return 15.0
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i searched for missing methods, but i did n't find. If you know what is missing methods. please list out them.

Comment: Actually u just remove the `func pieChartView(_ pieChartView: ORKPieChartView, valueForSegmentAt index: Int) -> CGFloat` and add the datasource method  which i mentioned above.....